# Уведомить UI об изменениях в базе данных

Tags: android, contentprovider, cursoradaper

В приложении под Android использую список, который использует данные из базы данных. Сейчас использую AsyncTaskLoader. Но он автоматом не подгружает новые данные. Поддерживает ли автоматическое обновление ContentProvider в связке с CursorAdapter? Есть ли смысл на него переходить?

Comment: Да, реализовывал ContentProvider в связке с CursorAdapter 2 дня назад, всё обновляется как надо!

Comment: @ua6xh, вручную вызывали notifyDataSetChanged или ContentProvider присылал новую порцию данных самостоятельно?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit - готово

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Поддерживает ли автоматическое обновление ContentProvider в связке с
> CursorAdapter? Есть ли смысл на него переходить?

Да, автоматическое обновление поддерживается. Имеет полный смысл переходить. И более того это рекомендованный паттерн. Это намного лучше чем всякие разные костыли.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ С этим как раз разбираюсь) Нужен для виджета..

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, я уже перешёл и очень доволен. Избежал очень многих проблем. Например, решился доступ к базе из разных потоков. Точнее, теперь у меня прямого доступа и нет. База открыта самим контент провайдером.

Comment: Не забывайте про `CursorLoader`!

Comment: ![alt text][1]

@Barmaley ♦ - Как так, если вопрос задал @Lucky_spirit? Это какие-то особые права на смену лучшего ответа? Или баг?


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/LCOqSGJ.png

Comment: @ua6xh нет, это на правах модератора - баллы за это деяние не начисляются. Если у вас убыло, могу компенсировать потери.

Answer (score 2):

[@Lucky_spirit](/users/1012/lucky_spirit) - Как я понял, это работает так: в `query` мы подписываемся:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), CIRCLE_CONTENT_URI);
```

В методах `delete`, `insert`, `update` уведомляем:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri, null);
```

Comment: @ua6xh.Такая же проблема возникла (с уведомлением). Вы говорите:
> В методах delete, insert, update уведомляем:
а что произойдет в момент уведомления? Как поймать этот момент и обновить необходимые мне данные?

Comment: @Мария_1 - Когда вызовется метод:

`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri, null);` 

на экране произойдет перестроение списка

Comment: @Мария_1 -  может быть я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: @ua6xh наверное правильно...А списка это например ListView вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Мария_1 - да, ListView. Если будут вопросы по контент провидеру - пишите на прямую, мои контакты есть в профиле.

Comment: @ua6xh, да вроде понятно что делать) Нужно разобраться как курсор приделать к ListView)
P.S. А в профиле написано только, что вы из Санкт-Петербурга...

Comment: @ua6xh Вы говорили, что можно к вам обратиться за помощью) Если не сложно, могли бы на примере показать как связать ContentProvider и ListView. Просто выше вы писали в комментарии:
> Да, реализовывал ContentProvider в связке с CursorAdapter 2 дня назад, всё обновляется как надо!